# C++ functions (surcharge & const)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code

```
//*********************************************
Section&
BasicConfig::section (std::string const& name)
{
    return map_[name];
}
//*************************************************
Section const&
BasicConfig::section (std::string const& name) const
{
    static Section none("");
    auto const iter = map_.find (name);
    if (iter == map_.end())
        return none;
    return iter->second;
}
```

if I write : `section("database_path");`

Which script will be executed ?

Comment: Is the object you are calling it on `const` or not?

Comment: @Igor: He wouldn't learn much from simply trying it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley He should try several times.:)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, why? This is the best and fastest way to learn - execute the code and see what it does. Or maybe its just me?

Comment: @Igor The compiler can have a bug.:)

Comment: @Igor: If he simply calls it, he will see either one or the other called, and assume that's the answer to his question. It's not though. He will not know why that one was called, and he will not know what situation will cause the other one to be called (or that such a situation even exists).

Answer (score 4):

Let's expand

`section("database_path");`

to the entirely equivalent

`this->section("database_path");`

If `this` is `const` (i.e. the method containing the above is marked `const`), then the `const` version of the `section` is called. Else the non-`const` version is called.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. Look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string gs;

class C
{
    public:
        std::string& f(std::string const & s) { gs = "f()"; return gs; }
        std::string& f(std::string const & s) const { gs = "f() const"; return gs; }

        std::string a() const
        {
            return f("s");
        }

        std::string b()
        {
            return f("s");
        }

};

int main()
{
    C c1;
    C *c2 = &c1;
    const C c3;
    const C& c4 = c1;
    const C* c5 = &c1;
    C* const c6 = &c1;


    std::cout << "c1.a = " << c1.a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c1.b = " << c1.b() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c1.f = " << c1.f("s") << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "c2->f = " << c2->f("s") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c3.f = " << c3.f("s") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c4.f = " << c4.f("s") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c5.f = " << c5->f("s") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c6.f = " << c6->f("s") << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

output:

c1.a = f() const

c1.b = f()

c1.f = f()

c2->f = f()

c3.f = f() const

c4.f = f() const

c5.f = f() const

c6.f = f()